# What is the best way to use sock js client to communicate with websockets in angularJS

Tags: angularjs, websocket, sockjs

I've created socket connection and onmessage event, I'm getting notified on initial connection but after a page refresh, I'm getting listeners array blank in the event. what should I do to get it worked on page refresh also?

Answer (score 0):

On page refresh, the controller will be also reloaded. So if you have subscribed stomp client inside the reloaded controller a new socket connection will be created. Make sure to connect and subscribe with sockJs on controller start.

If you could put your code in the question it will be easier to understand whats wrong.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. actually there was problem with the async call and I fixed that.